# Is there an R function that gives a table as output when the input is taken from user?

Tags: r, shiny

This is the code I've used to take input from the user:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
        textInput(inputId = "name",label = "Enter Name",value="abc"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "gender",
           label = "Select your gender",
           choices = c("Female","Male","Other"),selected = NULL),
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "hobbies",
                 label = "select your hobbies",
                 choices=c("reading","singing","coding","sports")),
  selectInput(inputId = "exam",label = "Select exam",
          choices=c("MHCET","HSC","SSC")),
  numericInput(inputId="marks",label="Enter Marks",value=60),
  selectInput(inputId = "stream",label = "Select stream",
          choices=c("CE","EXTC","MECH","IT","PPT")),
  dateInput(inputId = "dob",label = "Select DOB",
        value = NULL,min=NULL,max=NULL,format="dd-mm-yyyy",
        startview = "month",weekstart = NULL,language = "en",width = NULL),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit",label = "Submit"),
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$submit,{   
print(as.table(input$name,input$gender,input$hobbies,input$exam,input$marks,input$stream,input$dob))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I need to find a way to show the output in the form of a table. I tried to use the file function to take input, but it doesn't allow to take different types of inputs.

I also tried to to use the print as.table function but got an event handling error.

The question is supposed to be solved using the shiny library.

Comment: Did you check `shiny::renderTable`?

Comment: SO is not for answering questions in HW or training classes

Comment: I did try renderTable but got an eventhandling error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are render table and render datatable functions in the base Shiny package. Hadley’s book on Shiny has a good intro on these https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-ui.html#tables

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot